# Average Time difference in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to calculate the average time difference, in hours/minutes/seconds, iterating on a field - in my example, for each different ip address.
Moreover, a column containing the count of each ip row.

My dataframe looks like:

```
date                  ipAddress
2016-08-08 00:39:00   98.249.244.22
2016-08-08 13:03:00   98.249.244.22
2016-08-20 21:37:00   98.211.135.179
2016-08-21 16:11:00   98.211.135.179
2016-08-21 16:19:00   98.211.135.179
2016-08-25 01:30:00   98.248.215.244
```

My desired output:

```
ipAddress         avg_time_diff    count
98.249.244.22     avg_diff_1         2
98.211.135.179    avg_diff_2         3
98.248.215.244    0                  1
```

A reproducicle df:

```
{u'date': {3233: Timestamp('2016-08-08 00:39:00'),
  3551: Timestamp('2016-08-08 13:03:00'),
  349036: Timestamp('2016-08-20 21:37:00'),
  349040: Timestamp('2016-08-21 16:11:00'),
  349049: Timestamp('2016-08-21 16:19:00'),
  378843: Timestamp('2016-08-25 01:30:00')},
 u'ipAddress': {3233: u'98.249.244.22',
  3551: u'98.249.244.22',
 49036: u'98.211.135.179',
 349040: u'98.211.135.179',
 349049: u'98.211.135.179',
 378843: u'98.248.215.244'}}
```

I have no clue where to start, it tried timediff but I am not sure I've understood how it works and how to iterate over rows as a "window function".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [applying different functions to dataframe columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns):

```
(df.groupby('ipAddress')
   .date
   .agg({'count': 'count', 
         'avg_time_diff': lambda group: group.sort_values().diff().mean()}))

# Output 
#                count  avg_time_diff
# ipAddress                           
# 98.211.135.179      2       00:08:00
# 98.248.215.244      1            NaT
# 98.249.244.22       2       12:24:00
```

Comment: The code works just fine. My idea is: if I want to plot (in a scatterplot), count vs. avg_time_diff, should I convert the avg_time_diff in a numeric format? @Alexander

Comment: You can access the seconds attribute of the result as follows: `.avg_time_diff.dt.seconds`